# How can I set a size limit for image attachments to a pdf

Tags: pdf, images, attachments

I work with an online school, and we want to give fillable pdf forms to students for assignments. For some of these, we ask them to attach images, but we want to prevent them from attaching excessively large images.

How we're currently doing this is creating a blank image, and in the prepare form view, we set its action to run javascript, and enter the following:

```
event.target.buttonImportIcon();
```

When clicked, the user can select an image, and it will be placed in the image box. However, there's no limit to the image size. I inserted a 23MB jpg, and it increased the pdf size by 38MB.

I'd like to do the following, but I don't know how to do any of them, or whether they're possible.

- Check file size before attaching.
- Scale the image down to the size of our image box.
- Adjust the jpeg quality

Comment: So are you are giving the students a pdf file that they attach a picture and give back to you, or is this a form on a website?

Comment: We give them a pdf, which they attach an image into, then return to us. We have a size limit when they upload the pdf back to us, but we want to prevent kids from bumping into that limit as much as possible.